# iMac 2011 can't log in -- Bluetooth keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

My Apple keyboard stopped working and I can't connect a new keyboard at the login screen. How can I get the new Bluetooth keyboard paired up without being able to login?

Comment: Please describe what went wrong in detail

Comment: An Apple keyboard should work if you connect it to USB; then you can figure out the pairing later.

Comment: My old keyboard died, got a new one but can't log in to pair it with my imac, when I try to log in can't use the keyboard would a USB keyboard work?

Comment: Get (as in beg, steal or borrow) an Apple keyboard with a cable, connect, login and then pair the new one.

Comment: If all you need to do is login so you can then access bluetooth settings, or install drivers for a non-Apple keyboard [if required] then all you need is literally any old keyboard that will connect to USB. Doesn't even need to be Mac-specific, so long as all you're doing is logging in. Macs can be fussy about PC keyboards if you need to access Recovery, but no issue just for login.

Comment: Thanks the USB keyboard got me in, but Bluetooth not seeing the keyboard